# Laravel Form post to url does not show anything when I DD my request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Basically, I am trying to send a post request via a modal which has form data to my controller to save some values. However, when I reach my controller and tried to dd my values, nothing happens in my terminal. Am I doing something wrong here?

**Controller :-**

```
public function acceptPayment(Request $request, $id){
    $input = $request->all();
    dd($input);
}
```

**Blade :-**

```
<div id="modal-remarks" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">Payment Summary</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <form id="feedback-form" name="feedback-form" action={{ url("/supplier/company-order/accept-payment/".$companyOrder->id) }} method="POST">
       {!! csrf_field() !!}
       <p><b>Payment Method</b></p>
       <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="cc">Credit Card</label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="cdm">Cash Deposit</label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="ofpx">Offline Payment</label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="cheque">Cheque</label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="others">Others</label>
       </div>
       <div class="content">
        <p><b>Remarks</b></p>
       <div class="form-group pad_t--15">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="remark"></textarea>
       </div>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sd btn--submit-feedback">Submit</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**Route :-**

```
Route::post('/supplier/company-order/accept-payment/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'CompanyOrderController@acceptPayment'
]);
```

In my terminal, when i click on submit, nothing happens. i cant debug this at all. is there something wrong here?

Comment: dump the result you're getting through dd();

Comment: as i said, i get nothing. it shows literally nothing, i dont even get any error messages, my console is literally blank

Comment: Route::post('/supplier/company-order/accept-payment/{id}', function(){

dd();
});

debug in route and check that you're in the right place

Comment: so i do a function in my web.php route?

Comment: so you are using javascript to submit this form? because your button isn't in the form or referencing that form

Comment: Just copy the above code in your route (web.php) and check that you're route is okay. You've to check few things : 
1. Your form action 
2. Route
3. Controller

Comment: actually, @lagbox is right, im an idiot who didnt see that the button was outside my form...

Answer (score -1):

you may use like below

```
#Controller

public function acceptPayment(Request $request){
$input = $request->all();
dd($input);
}


#Route

Route::post('/supplier/company-order/accept-payment', [
'uses' => 'CompanyOrderController@acceptPayment'
]);


#in html form just add the below line

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$companyOrder->id}}" />

#So the final HTML form should look like below.



    <div id="modal-remarks" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">Payment Summary</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           <form id="feedback-form" name="feedback-form" action="/supplier/company-order/accept-payment" methoenter code hered="POST">
           {!! csrf_field() !!}
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$companyOrder->id}}" />
           <p><b>Payment Method</b></p>
           <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="cc">Credit Card</label>
           </div>
           <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="cdm">Cash Deposit</label>
           </div>
           <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="ofpx">Offline Payment</label>
           </div>
           <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="cheque">Cheque</label>
           </div>
           <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="others">Others</label>
           </div>
           <div class="content">
            <p><b>Remarks</b></p>
           <div class="form-group pad_t--15">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="remark"></textarea>
           </div>
          </div>
          </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sd btn--submit-feedback">Submit</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use route's name instead of url . Don't use url

Like this

```
Route::post('/supplier/company-order/accept-payment','CompanyOrderController@acceptPayment')->name('routeName');

/* Form Action :  */

<form action="{{route('routeName')}}">...</form>
```